# how to correctly delete file from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a photo which I can upload to sever in my project and info about my photo store in database. This is how record in my database looks like: 
*Id*:1 ,  *Path:* ~/Upload/d8cd7f97-1da2-43f3-b43a-74e5c9f28731.JPG                    *DispayName*: 9.jpg ,  *IsMainImage*:True ,  *FurnitureId*:25 .
 So here is my method which delete file from server and database:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteFile(int Id)
{
    try
    {
        FurnitureImages furnitureImages = db.FurnitureImages.Find(Id);
        if (furnitureImages == null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            return Json(new { Result = "Error" });
        }

        //Remove from database
        db.FurnitureImages.Remove(furnitureImages);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //Delete file from the file system
        var path = Server.MapPath(furnitureImages.Path);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
        return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

In my view  I pass parametr to ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.deleteItem').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $ctrl = $(this);
            if (confirm('Do you really want to delete this file?')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteFile")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { Id: $(this).data('Id') }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (data.Result == "OK") {
                        $ctrl.closest('li').remove();
                    }
                    else if (data.Result.Message) {
                        alert(data.Result.Message);
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("There is something wrong. Please try again.");
                })

            }
        });
</script>
```

And finally call this function:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SecondaryImages.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].Path)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].DisplayName)
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.SecondaryImages[i].Path)" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="@Model.SecondaryImages[i].Id" class="deleteItem">X</a>
}
```

Model in this example is ViewModel. But it doesn't work , It writes me "There is something wrong. Please try again" , first condition If doesn't work, what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you hit F12 and inspect the server response?

Comment: @CodeCaster hi , i see a console and when I try to delete it writes here: POST http://localhost:61741/Furnitures/DeleteFile 500 (Internal Server Error).  Something wrong with my code

Comment: So check the logs to see what the error was. Or attach the debugger and step through the code to see what's going on.

Comment: @mason  okay ,  i tried waht you say , i get following error Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (131:390)
    at fire (jquery-3.1.1.js:3305)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-3.1.1.js:3435)
    at done (jquery-3.1.1.js:9244)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.js:9484)
(anonymous) @ 131:390
fire @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3305
fireWith @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3435
done @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9244
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9484

Answer (score 0):

Okay , problem was solved , my Id was null , so error was in this line

```
data: { Id: $(this).data('Id') }
```

It must be

```
 data: { Id: $(this).attr('data-Id') }
```

now we get right id and image will be delete from server and file system

Comment: That is incorrect (and `data('Id')` is the correct usage. Your inside an ajax call and `$(this)` is the ajax, not the element. Use `var id = $(this).data('Id');` before the `$.ajax()` and the use `data { Id: id },`